# Speakers are not working but headphones are working fine

Tags: sound, speakers

[image]

My laptopp is lenoo z5070.

When I checked sound sittings it is not showing my speakers

Comment: For my hardware it plays via speakers by default unless the headphones are plugged in.

Comment: There will be more knobs to turn, if you install PavuControl 'sudo apt install pavucontol' (without quotes).